# Sans doute vs sans aucun doute

Tags: expressions

> Viendrez-vous demain ? *Sans doute*.

Littré donne comme synonyme *assurément, certes*.

Je crois que sans doute est comme peut-être, probablement et qu'il faut rajouter aucun (*sans aucun doute*) pour signifier *certainement, absolument*, n'est-ce pas ?

Alors, quand cette nuance s'est-elle glissée ?

Bizarrement, Google Translate donne la même traduction en anglais pour toutes les deux tournures (without doubt). Mais je trouve que la tournure sans aucun doute aurait être traduit par undoubtedly, non ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sans doute et Sans aucun doute peuvent avoir le même sens: Il n'y a pas de doute sur le sujet, c'est certain. Cependant dans le langage courant on peut utiliser "sans doute" pour exprimer une probabilité élevée pour un événement de se produire, par exemple:

> Il va sans doute y arriver.

Ici le sens de la phrase serait "Il va très probablement y arriver". Tandis que quand on utilise "sans aucun doute" cela signifie que l’événement va se produire quoi qu'il advienne, c'est sûr et certain.